# Laravel "logging.php" - Understand how it is used

Tags: php, laravel, logging, monolog

I'm playing with Laravel `Log` and I'd like to understand how the file `logging.php` is "imported"/"used".

For example, the `daily` channel contains:

```
    'channels' => [
        'stack' => [
            'driver' => 'stack',
            'channels' => ['daily'],
        ],

        'daily' => [
            'driver'    => 'daily',
            'path'      => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
            'level'     => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
            'formatter' => \Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter::class,
            'formatter_with' => [
                'format' => "[%datetime%] - %channel%.%level_name%: %message% %context% %extra%\n",
                'dateFormat' => "Y-m-d H:i:s",
            ],
            'days'      => 7,
        ],
    ]
```

How `days => 7` is passed to `\Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler`, `$maxFiles` variable?

What are the others keys (like: `formatter`, `formatter_with`, `days`, 
ecc...) that I can use into the channel array?

Thank you.